# How to merge dictionary values where the key count varies

Tags: python, dictionary

i'm having trouble to merge the values of a dictionary whereas the dictionary varies in its key count

i found an working example using two lists like

```
t1 = [1,2,3]
t2 = ["a","b","c"]
output = list(zip(t1, t2))
```

which leads to `[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]`  ... first success.

But I need to zip all the values from a dictionary, which varies in the count of the key values. (Sometimes there are 2 keys in, sometimes 4 and so on..)

Is there a way to do the zip with a dynamic input, dependent on the count of the keys

Lets say

```
t1 = [1,2,3]
t2 = ["a","b","c"]
generated_rows = OrderedDict()
generated_rows['t1'] = t1
generated_rows['t2']=t2

output = list(zip(??*))
```

the expected output would be as above:

```
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
```

but the parameters of the zip method should somehow come from the dictionary in a dynamic way. The following variing dicts should work with the method:

```
d1 = {'k1':[0,1,2], 'k2':['a','b','c']}
d2 = {'k1':[0,1,2], 'k2':['a','b','c'], 'k3':['x','y','z']}
d3 = ...
```

solution (thanks to Todd):

```
d1 = {'k1':[0,1,2], 'k2':['a','b','c']}
o = list(zip(*d1.values()))
```

Comment: Can you add your expected output to your question?

Answer (score 2):

If your second piece of code accurately represents what you want to do with N different lists, then the code would probably be:

```
t1 = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
t2 = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
# And so on
x = []
x.append( t1 )
x.append( t2 )
# And so on
output = zip(*x)
```

You don't need the extra `list()` because `zip()` already returns a list. The `*` operator is sometimes referred to as the 'splat' operator, and when used like this represents unpacking the arguments.

A list is used instead of a dictionary because the 'splat' operator doesn't guarantee the order it unpacks things in beyond "whatever order the type in question uses when iterating over it". An ordered dictionary may work if the keys are selected to impose the correct ordering.

Comment: Sorry, Ruby syntax instead of Python.

Comment: thank you! that splat-operator is what i was looking for

Comment: i can't aggree on the "don't need the extra list()" , when i leave it out python only returns a zip object, no list

Comment: according to Todd's solution i've added the solution for the dictionary above